# BeforeSave Plugin is not working

Tags: magento2, plugin

Own plugin is not being executed when adding to cart with /guest-carts/:quoteId/items rest api. Nothing is logged.

```
<preference for="House\Encryption\Api\EncryptionInterface"
            type="House\Encryption\Model\Encryption" />

<type name="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Save" type="House\Encryption\Plugin\Save" />
</type>
```

```
class Save {

public function beforeSave(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem)
{
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $om->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
    $storeManager->log(100,print_r('aaaaa',true));

}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you ensure your module gets loaded e.g. by adding a debug statement into the classes constructor?

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading your post, you need to check the webapi.xml file in the Magento_Quote module to see the proper interface for the `/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/items` API.

```
<route url="/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/items" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartItemRepositoryInterface" method="save"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

So we need to correct your di.xml with the correct interface.

It should be this:

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartItemRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="EncryptionCartItemSave" type="House\Encryption\Plugin\Save" />
</type>
```

You also shouldn't need the `disabled="false"` - and the given `name` is pretty generic. I'd make it a little more unique.

Your plugin is also a little malformed. You need to include the 'subject' class as well as the parameters. Your current plugin will also break the system since it doesn't return the parameters.

```php
class Save {

    public function beforeSave(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartItemRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem
    ) {
        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storeManager = $om->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $storeManager->log(100,print_r('aaaaa',true));

        return [$cartItem];
    }
}
```